# JSON SelectToken returning null

Tags: json, parsing

This is a JSON string i have and i am trying to parse it to get the "price but it always comes back null, pasted below is what i have tried, can someone please help?

JSON String

```
    {
    "data": {
        "id": "529665606157020735",
        "metadata": {
            "product": {
                "offer": {
                    "price": "$72",
                    "in_stock": true
                }
            },
            "link": {
                "locale": "en",
                "title": "Missguided Lace Trim Crepe Bardot Romper | Nordstrom",
                "site_name": "Nordstrom",
                "description": "Free shipping and returns on Missguided Lace Trim Crepe Bardot Romper at Nordstrom.com. Playful lace insets trim the off-the-shoulder bodice of this breezy flutter-sleeve romper, while sweet scallops detail the hem to complete the look.",
                "favicon": "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/favicons/4f607a214d617b57b7e45330f8f9135392b7b569f688523cc64bff6e.png?944d8af95205d57ea43fd0128d28a846"
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

**Parsing Script :**

```
 jsonstring = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 JObject jresults = JObject.Parse(jsonstring);
 string price = (string)jresults.SelectToken("metadata.product.offer.price");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

**JSON :**

```
var obj = {
    "data": {
        "id": "529665606157020735",
        "metadata": {
            "product": {
                "offer": {
                    "price": "$72",
                    "in_stock": true
                }
            },
            "link": {
                "locale": "en",
                "title": "Missguided Lace Trim Crepe Bardot Romper | Nordstrom",
                "site_name": "Nordstrom",
                "description": "Free shipping and returns on Missguided Lace Trim Crepe Bardot Romper at Nordstrom.com. Playful lace insets trim the off-the-shoulder bodice of this breezy flutter-sleeve romper, while sweet scallops detail the hem to complete the look.",
                "favicon": "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/favicons/4f607a214d617b57b7e45330f8f9135392b7b569f688523cc64bff6e.png?944d8af95205d57ea43fd0128d28a846"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**script :**

```
var result = obj.data.metadata.product.offer.price;
console.log(result);
```

**Output :**

[image]

**Fiddle demo :** https://jsfiddle.net/o6upskoy/

Comment: Thanks @RohitJindal ! changing the path to string price = (string)jresults.SelectToken("data.metadata.product.offer.price"); fixed the problem.

Comment: @Melody upvote and mark this as a correct answer so, it will be useful for others also.